# Cosa sono le "impalcate"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Amava anche i tronchi bugnati come ha l'olmo, che ai bitorzoli ricaccia getti teneri e ciuffi di foglie seghettate e di cartacee samare; ma è difficile muovercisi perché i rami vanno in su, esili e folti, lasciando poco varco. Nei boschi,  preferiva faggi e querce: perché sul pino le **impalcate** vicinissime, non forti e tutte fitte d'aghi, non lasciano spazio né appiglio; ed il castagno, tra foglia spinosa, ricci, scorza,  rami alti, par fatto apposta per tener lontani.

Qualcuno di voi sa cosa sono le "impalcate"? Ho cercato il termine "impalcata", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nel testo da te citato le **impalcate** hanno il significato di una accezione di [impalcature](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impalcatura/) 
che puoi trovare su Treccani alla voce 2.:

> 2. In arboricoltura, disposizione delle branche di un albero quasi a verticillo: presente naturalmente nel fusto del ciliegio, può essere
>      ottenuta anche in altri alberi recidendo il tronco a una certa
>      altezza.

Tratto da [Il principio della ramificazione](http://cngeilaquila.blogspot.it/2009/11/il-principio-della-ramificazione.html), anche per spiegare il significato di verticillo:

> Ci sono piante la cui gemma apicale lascia le gemme secondarie
>   singolarmente lungo una spirale di crescita. Altre specie di piante
>   invece lasciano due gemme opposte tra loro e in modo alterno tra le
>   coppie. **Altre infine le dispongono secondo un verticillo; i rami di
>   queste piante, un giorno, saranno disposti a "palco".**

Nel caso del pino (conifere), ad esempio, il fusto cresce in verticale senza ramificarsi e i rami in cerchio attorno al fusto ed inoltre:

> Le piante arboree, la cui gemma apicale non muore mai, producono un
>   fusto alto e dritto, monocormico, coi rami ben più piccoli del tronco.
>   Queste in genere sono le conifere, ma anche alcune latifoglie.

Riassumendo: il pino crescendo forma **impalcate** ovvero rami fitti più piccoli del tronco e quindi meno resistenti, irti di aghi che rendono difficoltosa e pericolosa la scalata.

Comment: Infatti su [questo testo](http://venezian.altervista.org/Disegno_e_immagine/11._Calvino_paesaggi.pdf) appare il vocabolo "impalcature" invece di "impalcate".

Comment: E sul [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impalcare) appare l'espressione "impalcare un albero".